# Node Server Data Base Connection Lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a web app using express, and MySQL. I was able to publish the app on heroku for testing. The problem came after few minutes or seconds, the server throws the following error:

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
```

When I restart the server, I'm able to execute some successful calls to database, but after some minutes, the connection get lost.

This is the connection file I'm currently using, I will, change my credentials for placeholders, only for security purppose.

```
module.exports = {
HOST: 'mysql5044hostname',
USER: 'myUserName',//root
PASSWORD: 'thisIsMyPassword',
DB: 'default_schema'
};
```

Any help regarding this matter, will be appreciated.

Comment: what mysql module do you use? seems like MySQL server you use has connection timeout, and your nodejs code works in single connection mode without mysql connections polling enabled. So, when remote MySQL server closes connection, you application cannot reconnect

Comment: This might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vodolaz095 and @riscarrott thanks to both of you, I changed the logic based on the documentation you sent, and I was able to successfully connect to database without losing the  communication with the server.